# Poles of $f(z)=\frac{z}{1-(e^z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the Poles of $f(z)=\frac{z}{1-(e^z)^2}$

The possible poles of $f$ are all the points $1-(e^z)^2=0 \Rightarrow  z=k\pi i , k \in \mathbb{Z}$

My question is: how I can prove that indeed $k\pi i , k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are poles?

Comment: You should maybe revise your solution with $k=0$. Is this really a pole?

Comment: My question doesn't really refer  when $k=0$ i know this isn't a pole, i want to know how to prove all the other points are poles but i don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a suspected pole in $z_0$ is indeed a pole (and supposing you don't want to distinguish essential singularities and poles) it suffices to find a sequence $(z_n)_n$ with $z_n\to z_0$ such that $|g(z_n)|\to\infty$. A simple choice for your function (and $z_0\neq0$... ;) ) would be $z_n=z_0+\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $k$ is a non-zero integer. Note that
\begin{align*}
1 - (e^z )^2&  = 1 - e^{2z}  = 1 - e^{2\pi ik} e^{2(z - \pi ik)}  = 1 - e^{2(z - \pi ik)} \\ & = 1 - \left( {1 + 2(z - \pi ik) + \mathcal{O}((z - \pi ik)^2 )} \right) =- 2(z - \pi ik)(1 + \mathcal{O}((z - \pi ik)).
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to \pi ik} -2(z - \pi ik)\frac{{z}}{{1 - (e^z )^2 }} = \pi ik.
$$
This shows that $\pi i k$ is a pole of order $1$ for each non-zero integer $k$.